# Can't access .ONION websites using QT C++, How To do it?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tor

Can someone can tell me why my code does not work? I made a program using QT C++ to route through TOR, I can access normal websites and I have a different public IP but I can't access .ONION websites, I get no response and/or Host not found.

**EDIT: AFTER FURTHER INSPECTION I THINK THE PROBLEM IS THAT I NEED TO RESOLVE THE DNS FOR THE .ONION ADDRESS, HOW CAN I DO THAT?**

---

```
tester::tester(QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent)
{

}

 QTcpSocket socket ;
void tester::GetUrl()
{
    QNetworkProxy proxy;
    proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::DefaultProxy);
    proxy.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    proxy.setPort(9050);
    proxy.setCapabilities(QNetworkProxy::HostNameLookupCapability | proxy.capabilities());
    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);

    qDebug()<<"Connecting";
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    manager->setProxy(proxy);
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    //manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.whatsmyip.org"))); //works
   //test access to random .onion website
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://blackma6xtzkajcy2eahws4q65ayhnsa6kghu6oa6sci2ul47fq66jqd.onion/products.php")));


//test access to random .onion website via socket
        socket.setProxy(proxy);

        socket.connectToHost("http://blackma6xtzkajcy2eahws4q65ayhnsa6kghu6oa6sci2ul47fq66jqd.onion/products.php",9051);
        qDebug() << "\nTCP SOCKET Response...\n";
        if(!socket.waitForConnected(5000))
                 qDebug() << "Error: " + socket.errorString() +"\n";
}

void tester::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* Reply)
{
    qDebug() << "Response...\n";
    if (Reply->isOpen())
    {
        qDebug()<<Reply->read((5000));
        Reply->close();
    }

    qDebug() << "\nTCP SOCKET Response...\n";
    if(!socket.waitForConnected(5000))
             qDebug() << "Error: " + socket.errorString() +"\n";
}
```

Comment: shouln't you set the proxy type to `Socks5Proxy` or so. You can check whether the proxy capabilities include name resolution, if it does, then the socket should use the proxy to do the resolution.

Comment: I used Socket5Proxy too instead of Default but I get the same result. I don't know if the proxy has name resolution capabilities but I suspect that it's a name resolution problem. I can't find how to make socket use proxy for resolution in QT C++